# How to handle embed line breaks in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have created a table in AWS Athena like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.test_line_breaks (
  col1 string, 
  col2 string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 'separatorChar' = ',',
 'quoteChar' = '\"',
 'escapeChar' = '\\'
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://bucket/test/'
```

In the bucket I put a simple CSV file with the following context:

```
rec1 col1,rec2 col2
rec2 col1,"rec2, col2"
rec3 col1,"rec3
col2"
```

When I run data preview request `SELECT * FROM "default"."test_line_breaks" limit 10;` then Athena returns the following response:
[image: Athena query response]

How should I set `ROW FORMAT` to properly handle line breaks within the field values? So that `rec3\ncol2` appears in `col2`.

Answer (score 12):

The problem here is that the OpenCSV Serializer-Deserializer

> Does not support embedded line breaks in CSV files.

See [this documentation from AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html).

However, it might be possible to use [RegexSerDe](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/RegexSerDe.html).  Just remember that this Deserializer will take "[Java Flavored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846031/how-to-regex-apache-log-date-and-time-into-hive)" Regex.  So be sure to use an online Regex tool that supports that syntax in your debugging.

Edit:  Still working on the syntax for dealing with the embedded line feed `\n`.  However, here is a sample that handles two columns with optional quotes.  The following regex `"*([^"]*)"*,"*([^"]*)"*`  [worked](https://regex101.com/r/hF4fP8/13) on your line with the embedded return carriage.  However, I *think* the Presto Engine is only feeding it `rec3 col1,"rec3`.  I continue working on it.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.test_line_breaks (
  col1 string, 
  col2 string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = '"*([^"]*)"*,"*([^"]*)"*'
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://.../47936191';
```

Comment: Hi @Zerodf, thanks for your help and explanations. I think I would pre-process file prior to upload to Athena.

Comment: @antklim, that might be a good idea.  Often when working these kind of "big data" problems, I have found it best practice to fix the upstream tasks to ensure consistent output, rather than compensate for inconsistent output downstream.