# regex for access log in hive serde with newline

Tags: regex, hive, newline, hive-serde, regexserde

With aws athena services, I try to import csv file including new line data

Importing data uses hive serde format.

If data is like this, (each data is enclosed in double quotes. "")

> "DataA"|"DataB"|"DataC"
>   "Data1"|"Data2
>   with new line"|"Data3"
>   "Data가"|"Data2나"|"Data나"

then how to write regular expressions to below table DDL?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ssdm_schema.ABCTable_regex (  
  Data_A VARCHAR(100)  
, Data_B VARCHAR(100)  
, Data_C VARCHAR(100)  
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'  
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (  
"input.regex" = '?????????'  
)
```

I'm asking to this question referring to the following answer.

[How to handle embed line breaks in AWS Athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936191/how-to-handle-embed-line-breaks-in-aws-athena)

Thank you

Comment: I reproduced the problem at https://regex101.com/r/bYF1Zm/1 using regex101 or a similar tool helps others see what you have already tried.

Comment: Almost there, https://regex101.com/r/bYF1Zm/2 Just need to handle the unicode next.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. https://regex101.com/r/bYF1Zm/3

`"([\w\s\n\r\X]+?)"\|"([\X\w\s\n\r]+?)"\|"([\X\w\s\n\r]+?)"` with the `g`lobal and `u`nicode flags set.

There were three things making this tricky:

1. The line break in the middle of the data on line 2
2. The white space in the middle of the data on line 2
3. The unicode

This regex can probably be more succinct because the matching pattern repeats.